# How to have 2-way communication between services?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I currently have 2 directives:

```
<div ng-controller="indexViewModel">
    <div class="row">
        <searchfilters></searchfilters>
    </div>
    <div class="row top-buffer">
        <searchfields></searchfields>
    </div>
</div>
```

They both have a `templateUrl` specified, and call 2 separate services that handle a list of items that each has.

```
var SearchFiltersService= angular.module('SearchFiltersService', [])
.service('SearchFilters', function () {
    this.MyList = [];
    return this;
});

var SearchFieldsService= angular.module('SearchFieldsService', [])
.service('SearchFields', function () {
    this.MyList = [];
    return this;
});
```

I don't want to provide too much code as I think I may be thinking of this problem incorrectly. I have run into cyclical dependency issues among others.

How can I have 2 templates, that each has a service (Just a list of items as its only property), where each service can add and delete items, that will be reflected in the other service (And in the other's view)?

Comment: Best practice here is probably to have both your directives depending on a single shared service instead of two separate but highly interdependent services.

Comment: @DanielBeck I tried something similar to this, but the lists between the services are not identical. They both however, need to be able to modify each other's list. Should a single shared service in this instance have 2 lists for each of them, and they both call this service, which will modify both lists?

Comment: Depends on the purpose for the different-but-related lists, I suppose, but in general you want to reduce interdependencies between components as much as possible.   If it's something like "anything added to list A should also be added to list B" you'll definitely want a single service managing both lists.

Comment: While a single service is probably better, if it can't be helped, you will need a third service through which the two services can communicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `Daniel Beck` gave a good answer in the comments, for how to deal with 2 services that need to communicate data with each other, in this case 2 lists.
The following shows a shared service that can handle adding items, and then further logic could be implemented to alter the lists depending on which child service the item is being inserted into.

```
var SearchSharedService= angular.module('SearchSharedService', ['SearchFiltersService', 'SearchFieldsService'])
.service('SearchShared', function (SearchFilters, SearchFields) {

    this.addFilter = function(filter) {
        //Perform logic to change filterto desired format for each child service
        SearchFilters.myList.push(filter);
        SearchFields.myList.push(filter);
    };

    this.addField = function(field) {
        //Perform logic to change field to desired format for each child service
        SearchFilters.myList.push(field);
        SearchFields.myList.push(field);
    };
    return this;
});

var SearchFiltersService= angular.module('SearchFiltersService', [])
.service('SearchFilters', function () {
    this.myList = [];
    return this;
});

var SearchFieldsService= angular.module('SearchFieldsService', [])
.service('SearchFields', function () {
    this.myList = [];
    return this;
});
```

NB: The shared service will need to be included in your module

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['SearchSharedService']);
```